# Calculating the percentage change relative to a fixed date

Tags: python

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tickers_list = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'AMD']
df = yf.download(tickers_list,'2022-1-1')['Adj Close']

def percentChange(start,current):
    return((current-start)/start)*100
    
for column in df.columns:
    start = df[column][0] 
    for eachPrice in df[column]:      
        change=percentChange(start, eachPrice)
        print(change)
        
# Show the graph
plt.plot(change)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('% Change')
plt.title("Action price of {} from {} to today".format(", ".join(tickers_list), start_date))
plt.legend(df.columns)
plt.show()
```

Hi. I use this code to get the data on three stocks from yahoo finance since 2022-01-01 till today. I want to calculate the percentage changes relative to 2022-01-01 in Python. It calcultes the %changes but stores all values in one column. How should I modify this code?
I want to produce a graph like the attached graph:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZpRI.png)

Comment: Hi, can you show us what you have tried ? Maybe look around matplotlib and numpy ? ;)

Comment: @totok The person who introduced this website to me, told me that there are some people here who just want to make fun of beginners. however, he said I have to ask my questions.

Comment: I'm sorry if you took that bad, I was not making fun of you. The way of asking questions on StackOverflow is to show what you tried, so the people can build on it. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a question, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to create a minimal reproductible example to focus on the problem

Comment: @totok Sorry. I will keep that in mind. Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the data
tickers_list = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'AMD']
start_date = '2022-1-1'
df = yf.download(tickers_list, start_date)['Adj Close']

# Calculate the change in percent for each column of the array
for column in df.columns:
    first = df[column][0]
    last = df[column][-1]
    change = 100 * (last-first)/first
    print("{} change: {:.2f}%".format(column, change))

# Show the graph
plt.plot(df)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Action price ($)')
plt.title("Action price of {} from {} to today".format(", ".join(tickers_list), start_date))
plt.legend(df.columns)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed
AAPL change: -19.18%
AMD change: -40.16%
TSLA change: -29.96%
```

[image: matplotlib graph]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code generates three single numbers. I need three time series including the % change in price in each day relative to 2022-01-01. In the next step, I need the graph of % changes rather than the graph of the prices.

Comment: Starting from this code, you can try doing it by yourself, and propose an edit to the answer / post your own answer. With numpy, you can do the percentage calculation I did on the last value to all values of all three columns, then show the percentage graph instead of the raw data graph as I did. I'm sure you can do it ! Show us that you tried, and we will continue to help you ;)

Comment: I added an answer including the code that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MatPlotLib as follows:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
# use the df you got in your code and get the 2 axis information and put them as arrays in these x and y variables:
x=[1,3,5,7]
y=[2,4,6,1]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title("A simple line graph")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I want to calculate the percentage change in comparison to 2022-01-01.